# Why is this equation valid in the carnot cycle?

Tags: carnot-cycle

I'm following a derivation [here](http://www.peter-junglas.de/fh/vorlesungen/thermodynamik1/html/kap3-5-4.html) of a carnot-cycle

[image: picture]

and I'm stuck at

$ T_3 / T_1 = T_4 / T_1 = (V_1 / V_4)^{(κ - 1)} = T_3 / T_2 = (V_2 / V_3)^{(κ - 1)} $

I don't get that. Is that due to mathematical reasons or is there a physical meaning behind it?

Comment: It is simply a matter of combining the ideal gas equation with the isentropic process equation for an ideal gas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a property of isentropic or adiabatic curves in general, where the constant $ \kappa $ depends on the specific heat capacity of the gas under consideration.

Recall the fundamental thermodynamic relation $ dU = T dS - p dV $. In an isentropic process, we have $ dS = 0 $, so $ dU = -p \, dV $. On the other hand, we have $ U = cNT $ where $ N $ is the number of particles and $ c $ is a constant related to the internal degrees of freedom of the gas particles. Using the ideal gas law $ PV = NRT $ gives

$$ \frac{c}{R} (P dV + V dP) = - P dV $$

or

$$ \frac{dP}{P} = -\left( \frac{c}{R} + 1 \right) \frac{dV}{V} $$

which is is a differential equation solved by $ P \sim V^{- \kappa} $, where $ \kappa = c/R + 1 $ is a constant depending on the specific heat properties of the gas being studied. Using the ideal gas law again and using the fact that $ N $ remains constant throughout an adiabatic process gives $ T \sim V^{1 - \kappa} $, so that

$$ \frac{T_2}{T_1} = \left( \frac{V_2}{V_1} \right)^{1 - \kappa} = \left( \frac{V_1}{V_2} \right)^{\kappa - 1} $$

in such a process. The equalities $ T_3 = T_4 $ and $ T_1 = T_2 $ just follow from the fact that the horizontal curves are isotherms, i.e. curves on which temperature is constant.

Comment: That was fast, thank you! I will study it in detail and then probably accept it :)

Comment: You shouldn't be provided complete solutions to a homework and exercise type problem. See my comment to OP which is an example of how far one should only go.

Comment: it is not a homework as you can see I posted a link where I stumbled over that expression..  I left university some years ago.. ;)